# jQuery, JavaScript - Network Error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on building a Javascript/jQuery and AJAX website. However, while testing I am encountering the following error:

```
Timestamp: 6/11/2016 10:13:45 AM
Error: NetworkError: A network error occurred.
```

To me, the most obvious culprit would be the AJAX call made in my script; however, I tried commenting it out and still received the same error. When the website is first loaded it displays three alert boxes (selection=category&detail=test, and so on), but then the error appears and changing the selection does not trigger the alert.

Here is my main page:

```
<?php
include('header.php');
?>

<div id='mainContent'>

<?php /* if(!$_SESSION['admin']) {
echo "<p>You do not have permission to view this page!</p>";
} else { */
echo "<form method='post' action='addItem.php'> 

<div class='form-group'>
<label>Category</label>
<select id='categorySelection' name='categorySelection'>
<option value=1>Playstation</option>
<option value=2>Wii</option>
<option value=3>Gamecube</option>
<option value=4>N64</option>
<option value=5>Other Console</option>
<option value=6>DS</option>
<option value=7>Game Boy</option>
<option value=8>Other Handheld</option>
<option value=9>DVD</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class='form-group'>
<label>Item</label>
<select id='itemSelection' name='itemSelection'>
</select>
</div>

<div class='form-group'>
<label>Condition:</label>
<select id='conditionSelection' name='conditionSelection'>
<option value=1>Acceptable</option>
<option value=2>Good</option>
<option value=3>Very Good</option>
<option value=4>New</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class='form-group'>
<label>Price: </label>
<input id='itemPrice' type='text' name='itemPrice' />
</div>

<div class='form-group'>
<label>Description: </label>
<textarea id='itemDescription' name='itemDescription'></textarea>
</div>
</form>";
 // }
?>

</div>
<script>

function selectionHandler(selectedAction, selectedValue) {
var gameData = "selection=" + selectedAction + "&detail=" + selectedValue;

alert(gameData);


 $.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'filter.php',
data: gameData,
success: function(returnData) {

if(selectedAction == 'category') {
$('#itemSelection').html(returnData);
} if(selectedAction == 'game') {
$('#itemPrice').val(returnData)
} else {
$('itemDescription').val(returnData);
} 

} // end return
});   // end ajax 
} // end handler

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#categorySelection").on("change", selectionHandler('category', "test" ) ) ;
$("#itemSelection").on('change', selectionHandler('game',  "test" ) );
$("#conditionSelection").on('change', selectionHandler('condition',  "test" ) );

}); // end ready
</script>
<?php

include('footer.php');
?>
```

and my PHP

```
<?php
include("header.php");
$db = new pdoAccess("localhost","root","");

$selection = $_POST['selection']; // either game, category, or condition

$detail = $_POST['detail'] // either categoryID or ISBN/Item ID
if($selection == 'category') {
$products = $db->filterByCategory($detail);
$html = "";
foreach($products as $product) {
$html += "<option value={$product->upc)}>$product->title</option>";
}
return $html;
} elseif ($selection = 'game') {
return $db->getProductPrice($detail);
} else {
return $db->getCategoryDescription($detail);
}

?>
```

Thanks!

EDIT: It should be noted that I also tried other events such as focusout and select. Same issue.

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't coming from your php? Like the pdo db connection?

Comment: Thanks, but I am quite sure. The only script unique to the page is 'filter.php' which I commented out along with the entire AJAX request. The rest of the site works fine and it would definitely fail if there was something wrong with my PDO connection. Oddly enough, I actually do get that error on other pages - I just never noticed it because it does not affect the functionality. Is it possible something with the CDN link (to jQuery) could be the problem? Thanks again.

Comment: What I would suggest is move your ajax code into your document ready block. It is possible it is trying to use something that was not done loading yet. Even better would be if you move it into a function, then on error you can simply call the function again. So for example if someone lost internet connection it will keep on trying until they have a connection again. Other than that I do not know. You can check the status variable if it is equals to success and then execute your code and if not console.log something to test.

Answer (score 0):

In php string cocatinating is by dot `.`  and use quotes also change here like this

```
 $html .= "<option value='{$product->upc)}'>{$product->title}</option>";
```

Also use double `==` to compare here

```
 } else if ($selection == 'game') {
```

Use echo in ajax instead of return

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out (I have not even gotten to debugging the PHP yet); however it does not resolve the problem. I specified complete, error, and success functions for the PHP. Both the complete and success functions fire the first time (when the page) loads, but after that, it just seems as if the JavaScript 'breaks'. Changing the selection does not produce even the first alert message. Thanks again though.

Comment: From where you are calling selectionHandler

Comment: Use echo in ajax instead of return

Comment: You should call selectionHandler from outside of function